# Conditional request from SSRS 2005 DataSet in an expression

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm having difficulty with what seems to be a limitation in SSRS (BIDS) 2005, and upgrading to a newer version is not yet an option for me.

I have a DataSet that returns a bunch of payroll withholding data by employee, and I'm wanting to get the value of field "B" based on what I find in field "A."  Specifically, I want to get a dollar amount based on a field "Code" being "OptlLife."

So, if Field A = "OptLife" give me the dollar value of Field B.  Pretty simple, right?

The closest I can come is:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Code.Value, "Withholdings") = "OptLife", First(Fields!AmtPct.Value, "Withholdings"), " ")
```

What's killing me is that "First" indicator.  I don't want "first" or "last" or "max" or "sum."  I want whatever row of data has the value OptLife.  If I remove that indicator, I get a syntax error.  How do I get around this?

What I really want is something like "select AmtPct from WithholdingsDataSet where Code = "OptLife" but it needs to be an SSRS expression.

EDIT PER IAN'S QUESTION:

So, I have a result set from the DataSet that looks like this.

```
Employee    Code        Method  AmtPct
1121        401K        A       400
1121        Roth        null    null
1121        FSAChild    A       96.15
1121        FSAHealth   A       192.31
1121        OptLife     A       28.84
```

In my report, I have a textfield formatted for Currency, and need an expression that will pull the 28.84 into that field.  Because I have multiple DataSets tied to this report, I need to specify which DataSet the value is coming from, hence the (Fields!Code.Value, "Withholdings") but that parenthetical statement has to be prepended with something.  Nothing I put there gives me the value I need.

Once I nail this down, the same methodology will be used for distinguishing Roth and Traditional 401K, and FSA Childcare from FSA Healthcare.

Comment: Based on your example SQL statement it seems like you're looking for a filter. Is it possible to give an example dataset and expected results?

Comment: Ian, I'll try to modify the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Code.Value = "OptLife", Fields!AmtPct.Value, Nothing), "Withholdings")
```

As you've seen, since you're referencing the data in a Textbox you need to use an aggregate expression.

The expression above will apply a `Sum` to the dataset, but will only consider `OptLife` rows, which seems to be what you're after. Assuming you only have one `OptLife` code in the Dataset, you'll only be considering that one row in the aggregate, which I think is what is required.

Comment: Sweetness!!!  Yes!  This works Ian, and I understand what you're saying.  I can use this very same approach in other places (even other reports) where I have encountered this problem.  Thank you!